# How get get preferences from the iphone app to a server

Tags: iphone, xcode, preferences

Noobie Question. I am not after the code but rather the general process to get the preferences picked in my app are to be stored on a server.
1. how should I store this on the iphone (table ; array; dictionary or just various textboxes) and 2. What process to do I use to get them from the phone/app to the server. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options available to you; here are two:

For a small number of preferences, you could encode them in a URL as parameters and pass them to your server by making a request using using NSURLConnection / NSURLRequest.

For more parameters, you could place them in a NSDictionary and use a JSON library to serialize them out as a string, which you could POST to your server.